# Each day when the logs turn over, the system fails to find space even though there is plenty on the device; potential error with init.d script

Tags: ssh, disk-usage, init.d, logrotate

I'm still at a loss for this specific error and any help or pushing in the right direction would be much, much appreciated.

TL;DR: Many, many instances of an `init.d` spawned script seem to be running, taking up all space on the server and messing with essential functions. Not sure how to course correct or diagnose further.

Full background:

So basically, the error became apparent when I would lose the ability to `ssh` into the remote server after a period of time. Basically, the password would stop working. I looked around a lot and found that it was likely because the system was running out of space and had no room to check the password. (I will note that using ssh-agent and generating a key works for login somehow; just not normal ssh.)

Within the `syslog` I found that each day, after `00:00:00` the following would be printed:

```
Jun 21 00:00:18 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Jun 21 00:00:18 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
Jun 21 00:05:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER snapd[545]: autorefresh.go:528: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jun 21 00:05:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER snapd[545]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jun 21 00:09:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER CRON[169859]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jun 21 00:09:02 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jun 21 00:09:02 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER kernel: [467998.141843] systemd-journald[170]: Failed to save stream data /run/systemd/journal/streams/8:4052447: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:09:02 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Jun 21 00:09:02 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Jun 21 00:09:03 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-networkd[489]: Failed to save network state to /run/systemd/netif/state: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:09:03 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-timesyncd[427]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 21 00:09:03 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-resolved[492]: Failed to write private resolv.conf contents: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:09:14 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-timesyncd[427]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.5.0.5:123 (10.5.0.5).
Jun 21 00:17:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER CRON[169924]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 00:30:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER snapd[545]: autorefresh.go:528: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jun 21 00:30:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER snapd[545]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jun 21 00:39:01 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER CRON[169961]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-networkd[489]: Failed to save network state to /run/systemd/netif/state: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-resolved[492]: Failed to write private resolv.conf contents: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd-timesyncd[427]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER kernel: [469799.368812] systemd-journald[170]: Failed to save stream data /run/systemd/journal/streams/8:4064685: No space left on device
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Jun 21 00:39:04 SERVER-NAME-PLACEHOLDER systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
```

Which seemed to indicate that it was a space problem. Interestingly, on server reset, everything begins working okay and is totally fine.

So I began investigating the typical culprits:

1. `df -i /`

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root      19200000 779105 18420895    5% /
```

2. `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       146G   38G  108G  27% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           766M  766M     0 100% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       27M   27M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop3       26M   26M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656
/dev/loop4       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop5       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15904
/dev/loop6       47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16010
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop8       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/loop9       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
tmpfs           766M     0  766M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           766M   20K  766M   1% /run/user/126
```

3. `du -sh /`

```
...
35G     /
```

4. `lsof / | grep deleted`

[nothing comes up]

I've also checked `htop`:

[image]

It seems to indicate that multiple uses of Blazegraph are running and taking up the space:

[image]
[image]

I'm a bit confused by this... So I have set Blazegraph (and its updater) within the `init.d` folders as services, but they should only start once right? There's no reason why it would spawn so often that I can think of.

My `init.d` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          blazegraph
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: blazegraph jetty server
# Description:       Start blazegraph on a jetty server
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT='sudo BLAZEGRAPH_OPTS="-DwikibaseConceptUri=https://placeholder.com" bash /var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/wikidata-query-rdf/dist/target/service-0.3.111-SNAPSHOT/runBlazegraph.sh'

PIDFILE=/var/run/blazegraph.pid

start() {
  if [ -f /var/run/$PIDNAME ] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/$PIDNAME); then
    echo 'Service already running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Starting serviceâ€¦' >&2
  local CMD="$SCRIPT"
  su -c "$CMD" > "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service started' >&2
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    echo 'Service not running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Stopping serviceâ€¦' >&2
  kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service stopped' >&2
}

uninstall() {
  echo -n "Are you really sure you want to uninstall this service? That cannot be undone. [yes|No] "
  local SURE
  read SURE
  if [ "$SURE" = "yes" ]; then
    stop
    rm -f "$PIDFILE"
    #echo "Notice: log file is not be removed: '$LOGFILE'" >&2
    update-rc.d -f <NAME> remove
    rm -fv "$0"
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  uninstall)
    uninstall
    ;;
  retart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|uninstall}"
esac
```

As well, everything with the application seems to work? The Blazegraph updates and is queryable; changes on the front-end show up fine. Even when there is said to be no space, these processes seem to run without issue.

Any ideas? I'm wondering if this is an error in how I set up the `init.d` service? I met with a project manager with Wikibase and she's never seen this error and it doesn't seem to be documented with Blazegraph, which makes me think it's a services error?